# Continue the search inside a DO loop

Tags: if-statement, fortran, fortran77

I wrote a simple FORTRAN code in order to do the following: assume we have to integer numbers n1 and n2 which have common divisors. For example 3 and 6 both are divided by 3. Here is the code

```
PROGRAM test

INTEGER i,n1,n2

WRITE(*,*)' Please enter two numbers: '
READ(*,*)n1,n2

DO i=2,10,1
  IF(MOD(n1,i).EQ.0.AND.MOD(n2,i).EQ.0)THEN
     n1=n1/i
     n2=n2/i
  ENDIF
    n1=n1
    n2=n2
ENDDO

WRITE(*,*)n1,n2

PAUSE

END
```

This works fine for the example (3,6). However, there are cases like (4,8) in which the numbers have more than one common divisor, in this case 2 and 4. Another example (16,24). I want to compute the maximum common divisor of the two numbers and then reduce them (i.e. 3,6 to 1 and 2), but the code returns the first one (4,8 returns to 2, 4 instead of 1,2). How should it be modified in order to calculate the maximum divisor?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What about [Euclid's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)?

Comment: @Stefan How could this be incorporated to my simple code? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could stay with an `i`, till your `if`-statement is `false`.

---

In other words:

If a number can be divided by `i`, then don't immediately go to `i+1`, but try to divide by `i` again.

---

**EDIT:** I think the easiest way is to use a `DO WHILE`-loop. To calculate the divisor, you have to multiply all your `i`.

```
gcd = 1
DO i=2,10,1
  DO WHILE (MOD(n1,i).EQ.0.AND.MOD(n2,i).EQ.0)
     n1=n1/i
     n2=n2/i
     gcd = gcd * i
  ENDDO
ENDDO
WRITE(*,*) gcd
```

Comment: I thought of it! But again how this could be incorporated to my code? I mean the specific changes needed.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [greatest common divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor). You may do this:

```
function gcd(a, b)
   implicit none
   integer a, b, aa, bb, cc, gcd

   aa = abs(a)
   bb = abs(b)
   do while (bb .ne. 0)
      cc = mod(aa, bb)
      aa = bb
      bb = cc
   end do
   gcd = aa
end
```

Note: it is written in [Fortran 77](http://www.fh-jena.de/~kleine/history/languages/ansi-x3dot9-1978-Fortran77.pdf) + [MIL-STD-1753](http://www.everyspec.com/MIL-STD/MIL-STD-1700-1799/download.php?spec=MIL-STD-1753.011044.PDF) (for the DO WHILE construct and IMPLICIT NONE).